# Date time conversion in R from datetime format to datemonth

Tags: r, datetime

I have two columns in R which are like:

```
2004-07-08 14:30:00         12.41
```

Now, I want to transform the first column that is the date time column to datemonth column only.
like:

```
8 July       12.41
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: where ends the first column? Next time please do format well the code.

Comment: @akrun posted this answer but then deleted it for some reason: `format(as.POSIXct(df$col1), '%d %B')`

Answer (score 2):

We can use `format`

```
format(as.POSIXct(str1), '%d %B')
#[1] "08 July"
```